# How to check for BackgroundWorker cancellation between each of multiple function calls

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, function-call, cancellation

I have a `BackgrounWorker` that calls vairous methods from a custom class called `ExcelOutput`. The below function works, but it does not allow me to check for cancellation.

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object,
                      ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim UserDump As New CurrentUserDumpInfo(Me.MainForm.ConfigForm) ' Create a new instance of the CurrentUserDumpInfo
    Dim Excel As New ExcelOutput(Me)                                ' Create a new instance of the ExcelOutput 
    Dim FirstRow As Integer = 4                                     ' The row on which the output should start
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer                                       ' The currnet row on which the output shoud continue

    '** Prepare the CurrentUserDumpInfo and the ExcelOutput *'
    Call UserDump.prepare()
    Call Excel.Prepare()

    CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("General", UserDump.lstGeneralHeaders, UserDump.lstGeneralData, FirstRow)
    CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("Address", UserDump.lstAddressHeaders, UserDump.lstAddressData, CurrentRow + 2)

    Call Excel.AutofitContents(4, CurrentRow)
    Call Excel.AlignCells(4, CurrentRow)
    Call Excel.StyleWorksheet()
    Call Excel.MakeSafeCopy()
    Call Excel.LockWorksheet()
    Call Excel.Finish(UserDump.CurrentUser.FullName)

End Sub
```

To do this, I've set each methods listed above to check for errors (using `Try/Catch`), and if there is an error, I <s>set `bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True`</s> call the `bw.CancelAsync()` method (you'll notice I pass `Me` when initiating the `ExcelOutput` instance, making this possible).

This method works, but to implement it fully I have to wrap every call in an `If` block like so, making the code very long and difficult to read (each call goes from 1 line to 6 lines) -

```
If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
    e.Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("General", UserDump.lstGeneralHeaders, UserDump.lstGeneralData, 4)
End If
```

Is there a better way to do this, that will both keep the code short and sweat but offer the functionality of the cancellation check? Thanks.

## Update

Thanks to the answer below, here is the exact `bw_DoWork()` method that I am now using, which achieves exactly what I was looking for -

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object,
                      ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim UserDump As New CurrentUserDumpInfo(Me.MainForm.ConfigForm) ' Create a new instance of the CurrentUserDumpInfo
    Dim Excel As New ExcelOutput(Me)                                ' Create a new instance of the ExcelOutput 
    Dim FirstRow As Integer = 4                                     ' The row on which the output should start
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer                                       ' The currnet row on which the output shoud continue

    Dim Counter As Integer = 0
    While Not bw.CancellationPending = True

        Select Case Counter

            Case 0 : Call UserDump.prepare() : Exit Select  ' Prepare the CurrentUserDumpInfo object ready for use
            Case 1 : Call Excel.Prepare() : Exit Select     ' Prepare the ExcelOutput object ready for use

            Case 2 : CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("General", UserDump.lstGeneralHeaders, UserDump.lstGeneralData, FirstRow) : Exit Select
            Case 3 : CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("Address", UserDump.lstAddressHeaders, UserDump.lstAddressData, CurrentRow + 2) : Exit Select
            Case 4 : CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("Account", UserDump.lstAccountHeaders, UserDump.lstAccountData, CurrentRow + 2) : Exit Select
            Case 5 : CurrentRow = Excel.OutputGroup("Profile", UserDump.lstProfileHeaders, UserDump.lstProfileData, CurrentRow + 2) : Exit Select

            Case 6 : Call Excel.AutofitContents(4, CurrentRow) : Exit Select
            Case 7 : Call Excel.AlignCells(4, CurrentRow) : Exit Select
            Case 8 : Call Excel.StyleWorksheet() : Exit Select
            Case 9 : Call Excel.MakeSafeCopy() : Exit Select
            Case 10 : Call Excel.LockWorksheet() : Exit Select
            Case 11 : Call Excel.Finish(UserDump.CurrentUser.FullName) : Exit Select

            Case Else : Exit While

        End Select

        Counter += 1

    End While

    '** Check to see if the BackgroundWorker should be cancelled *'
    If bw.CancellationPending = True Then e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It may be a typo, but the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property should "only" be set at design time. What you should do is set the `CancellationPending` property.

Comment: Good spot, it is a typo. I actually call the `bw.CancelAsync()` method, which is what sets `CancellationPending` I believe. I'll correct shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "common" rule not to use try/catch in a DoWork event. The exception is if you want to dispose or clean up objects. If an error occurs it will be available in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event (e.Error).

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

    Dim obj As IDisposable = Nothing
    Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing

    Try
        obj = New Control()
        Throw New Exception("Simulated exception")
    Catch ex As Exception
        [error] = ex
    Finally
        If (Not obj Is Nothing) Then
            obj.Dispose()
            obj = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

    If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
        Throw [error]
    End If

End Sub
```

With that being said, you can try to do the work in a  `While Loop`  and check for cancellation after each cycle.

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork

    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim num As Integer = Nothing
    Dim obj As IDisposable = Nothing
    Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing

    Try
        'TDOD: obj = New IDisposable ()
        num = 0
        While (Not e.Cancel)
            Select Case num
                Case 0
                    'Do somthing
                    Exit Select
                Case 1
                    'Do somthing
                    Exit Select
                Case 2
                    'Do somthing
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Exit While
            End Select
            num += 1
            e.Cancel = worker.CancellationPending
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        [error] = ex
    Finally
        If (Not obj Is Nothing) Then
            obj.Dispose()
            obj = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

    If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
        Throw [error]
    ElseIf (Not e.Cancel) Then
        'TODO: e.Result = Nothing 
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good call on using a `While` loop in conjunction with the `Select Case`. That is what I implemented, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good! Btw, if you want fewer lines: `Case 0 : Call UserDump.prepare() : Exit Select`

Comment: I've already used `Case 0 : Call UserDump.prepare()`. Can I assume `Exit Select` will the stop checking for future matches, thus potentially saving execution time (the same as `break` does for PHP)?

Comment: Say again, please? :p

Comment: Don't worry, I was just confirming exactly how the `Select Case` (and associated statements) worked, but I tested and figured it out. Thanks for the help.